# Kotlin: How to access properties in constructor

Tags: properties, delegates, kotlin

Consider following class:

```
class Test() {
    init {
        log(foo)
    }

    val foo = "Bar"
}
```

When I instatiate Test it produces a NullPointerException because foo doesn't seem to be initialized. Is this behaviour actually intended? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Note that current kotlin requires the initialization blocks to have the `init` keyword in front of them now.  This syntax in the question is outdated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The body of the class is executed from top to bottom. If you want something to run a piece of code after the property initialization, you should place it lower:

```
class Test() {
    val foo = "Bar"

    init {
        log(foo)
    }
}
```

Comment: Andrey, thanks for the answer. My problem was the compiler not allowing me to place the constructor after a delegated property because it thought the block was a lambda expression passed as a parameter. I figured out you can just place a semicolon after the property to prevent this. Marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: Note:  The `;` added by @Andrey is not needed to separate the initialization block in current Kotlin, instead you add the keyword `init` in front of the block.  This answer should be updated to current Kotlin.